# Connecting SQlite3 to UITextview

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am doing an iPad app, were i will have UITabelview and a Button and UiTextview in same screen. My task is that if i select some row in UITableview and press button the text has to be appeared on the UITextview.

I filled few methods but it didn't work can any one let me know what exactly i can do to complete this task successfully.

Please find my code below for your reference...it may help you to explain my problem.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "table1.h"
#import "textView.h"


@interface searchOne : UIViewController

{
    IBOutlet UITableView *firstTable;
    table1 *tableOne;
    textView * text1;
    int row;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton * search;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextView *txt;
@property(nonatomic, assign) int row;

-(IBAction)resPage:(id)sender;
@end
#import "searchOne.h"
#import "textView.h"

@implementation searchOne
@synthesize search;
@synthesize txt, row;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (tableOne == nil) {
        tableOne = [[table1 alloc] init];
    }

    [firstTable setDataSource:tableOne];

    tableOne.view = tableOne.tableView;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{   

    row = [indexPath row];


}   
-(IBAction)resPage:(id)sender{

    NSString *str = txt.text;
    row  = [str intValue];   
    NSLog(@"get clicked");
    self.view =txt;

}

/*
 // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 // Return YES for supported orientations
 return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
 }
 */

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}



- (void)viewDidUnload {
// [self setTxt:nil];
[super viewDidUnload];
                         }
@end
```

DB:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface db : NSObject{
    NSInteger ID;
    NSString * name;
}


@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property(nonatomic, readwrite) NSInteger ID;



-(id)initWithID: (NSInteger)i andName:(NSString *)n;

@end
@implementation db
@synthesize name,ID;

-(id)initWithID: (NSInteger)i andName:(NSString *)n{
    self=[super init];
    if(self)
    {
        self.ID = i;
        self.name = n;
    }
    return self;
}


@end
```

Tabel view:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "sqlite3.h"
#import "db.h"

@interface table1 : UITableViewController<UITableViewDataSource>{
    NSString *databaseName;
    NSString * databasePath;
    NSMutableArray * tableOne;

}
@property(nonatomic, retain)  NSMutableArray * tableOne;


-(void)checkAndCreateDatabase;
-(void)readDataFromDatabase;


@end

#import "table1.h"
#import "db.h"

@implementation table1
@synthesize tableTwo;

#pragma mark - View lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    databaseName=@"nobel10.db";

    NSArray *documentPaths= NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString * documentDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath=[documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    [self checkAndCreateDatabase];
    [self readDataFromDatabase];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


#pragma mark - TableView Data Source methods
-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [tableTwo count]; }

// Row display. Implementers should *always* try to reuse cells by setting each cell's reuseIdentifier and querying for available reusable cells with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
// Cell gets various attributes set automatically based on table (separators) and data source (accessory views, editing controls)

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell= nil;
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"mycell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"mycell"];}

    db * temp =(db *)[self.tableTwo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text=temp.name;
    return cell;
}


-(void)checkAndCreateDatabase{
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    success=[fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];
    if(success)
        return;

    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];
}
-(void)readDataFromDatabase{
    sqlite3 *database;
    tableTwo=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database)== SQLITE_OK){
        const char *sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM country";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK){
            while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSInteger pId = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 0);
                NSString *stringName=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
                db *info =[[db alloc]initWithID:pId andName:stringName];
                [tableTwo addObject:info];

            }            
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}



@end
```

UITextView:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "sqlite3.h"
#import "db.h"

@interface textView : UIViewController<UITextViewDelegate>{
    NSString *databaseName;
    NSString * databasePath;
    NSMutableArray *textOne;
   NSString *description;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *textOne;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *description;
-(void)checkAndCreateDatabase;
-(void)readDataFromDatabase;
-(id)initWithDescription:(NSString *)d;
@end

#import "textView.h"

@implementation textView
@synthesize textOne, description;;
#pragma mark - View lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    databaseName=@"nobel10.db";

    NSArray *documentPaths= NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString * documentDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath=[documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    [self checkAndCreateDatabase];
    [self readDataFromDatabase];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


#pragma mark - TableView Data Source methods


// Row display. Implementers should *always* try to reuse cells by setting each cell's reuseIdentifier and querying for available reusable cells with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
// Cell gets various attributes set automatically based on table (separators) and data source (accessory views, editing controls)


-(void)checkAndCreateDatabase{
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    success=[fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];
    if(success)
        return;

    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];
}
-(void)readDataFromDatabase{
    sqlite3 *database;
    textOne=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database)== SQLITE_OK){
        const char *sqlStatement = "SELECT name,item_country.id,text.item FROM country,item_country,text WHERE country.name ='India' AND country.id = item_country.id AND text.item =item_country.item ";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK){
            while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSInteger pId = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 0);
                NSString *stringName=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
                db *info =[[db alloc]initWithID:pId andName:stringName];
                [textOne addObject:info];

            }            
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
-(id)initWithDescription:(NSString *)d{
self.description = d;
    return self;
}

@end
```

PLease help me i am new to iPad development and struck here..

Comment: What is the relationship between these three classes?

Comment: Hi Ravin: one is Database, tableview and textview

Comment: So... What is your Question? How to make an insert or update with sqlite3?

Comment: Hi Alex I want to make a method(IBAction)by pressing a UIButton by which i can display the text in UItextview from Sqlite3 related to the row i selected in UITable.

Comment: @Hi Peter: its in searchOne classe, the UIButton by name search: and also and IB action -(IBAction)resPage:(id)sender; which is connected to theButton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty way is just to remove the UITextView, and add it back in when you select the row. See if that works.

Comment: Hi Hisoka Can you give me some Example or any link please?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is not the question you asked, but depending on your needs, you might want to use Core Data instead. It abstracts the .sqlite database from you and does some pretty cool things in terms of memory usage, modelling objects and relationships and so on.

Comment: I tried using CoreData and it was an absolute nightmare. I still don't get how people can recommend using it. The alternative is messy and tedious (writing manual queries), but I had problems when I had to change the schema of tables with CoreData.

Comment: We change schemas all the time, and they automatically upgrade existing data in the field. I agree there is a learning curve, but with any sufficiently advanced OR mapper there always is. YMMV though  - use what's best for you obviously.